# How to add conditional constraint on SQL columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table (`example_table`) with multiple columns, two of them being `soft_id` and `hard_id`.

`soft_id` and `hard_id` can be `null`, but if `soft_id` is not `null` then `hard_id` has to be not null as well (and vice versa. Essentially they are either both `null` or both `not null`).

I enforced this validation on the front end, but I have an existing bug that can occur if a user manually inserts bad data through the database. Some users do have write permissions to the database, so rather than taking away this permission I'd like to somehow enforce this constraint on the table.

I'm using javax for the table models, and it'd be cool if it could be enforced on the `ExampleTable` model there as well but not required for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt this with a [`check constraint`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html):

```
alter table example_table
add constraint either_id_set check (
    soft_id is null and hard_id is null
    or soft_id is not null and hard_id is not null);
```

Comment: From the description, shouldn't it be `soft_id is null and hard_id is null or soft_id is not null and hard_id is not null`?

Comment: also you can have update/insert trigger where you can put really complicated logic

Comment: @Fred you are correct, I edited my code accordingly

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly, but when I add this constraint and then update a `soft_id` on the table to be null (in a row where `hard_id` is not null), the update persists.

Comment: It's worth noting that CHECK constraints are not supported in versions of MySQL earlier than 8.0.16. If you try to define a table with a CHECK constraint in earlier versions, it results in no error, but it does not save the constraint or enforce it.

Comment: Gotcha, looks like I'm on 5.7.21

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to express the check constraint:

```
alter table example_table add constraint check_example_table_soft_hard as
    check ( (soft_id is null) = (hard_id is null) );
```

MySQL support for check constraints varies by version.

- They are supported directly in the most recent version.
- They are supported via views since 8.0 (I think).
- They require triggers in older versions.

The trigger looks something like this:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger trig_example_table_insert 
    before insert on example table
for each row
begin
    if ( (new.soft_id is null) = (new.hard_id is null) ) then
        signal sqlstate '45000'
               set message_text = 'soft_id and hard_id are not compatible';
    end;
end;$$
```

Comment: How would it be done with a trigger? It's not my server so I won't be able to upgrade it.